# ASPxGridView width of vertical scroll bar

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, devexpress, scrollbar

I am wondering how to get the width of a vertical scroll bar on an ASPxGridView.

Here are some more details:
I am trying to size a panel to be the same width as the ASPxGridView. The grid does not have its width property set. All columns have fixed widths. If I sum up all of the column widths on the server side and apply the result to the panel then I am still off by the width of the vertical scroll bar.
I can just inspect the element after its rendered and get the difference and hard code it... but I doubt that will work in all cases. Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control will have a width once it is rendered on the client side, so you can get the width of the gridview on the client side init function of the panel.

Init="function(s, e) {
s.SetWidth(ASPxGridView1.GetWidth());}"

Comment: Cool so I don't even need the width of the vertical scroll bar.... I should have thought of setting it on the client side!

Comment: Ya, it's very simple, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ...>
             <Columns>
             ....
            </Columns>
            <RowStyle Width="150px"/>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Try this, I think it works